# Spotify rate limits for logins

Tags: spotify

I read the information on Spotify's website about their rate limits, such as they are applied on an application basis and are higher with an authenticated requests. (https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/user-guide/#rate-limiting)

My question is whether it applies to logins as well as regular api requests.

So if we are making a large number of calls the api, enough that we are hitting the rate limit for our application, will this mean that users won't be able to log in to our site using Spotify (via the Authorization Code Flow) at the same time?

The Spotify docs seems a little vague on this, and also don't seem to have any concrete numbers on what the rate limits actually are.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe the rate limits are token based not IP address based. Are you using their token to hit the API before they are logging in? If you are using you application token it shouldn't be an issue as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @chasenyc.  We have an site live that's using a Spotify app to allow people to log in. When they log in, we are storing their access token and at a later point, using it to run a task on the user's behalf.  We may end running this task for a great number of users at the same time, so may hit Spotify's rate limit.  It doesn't matter if this task is slowed down, but it would matter if people weren't able to still log in while the task is running.  The task and the login both use the same app, which is why I'm wondering if they login could be effected.